# How to disable loading images when using CURL?

Tags: curl

I want to load a site/url but i do not need the images. How do i exclude images from loading when I use CURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a call like `curl <url>` gives you only the plain HTML page and doesn't load the images. But if you want to remove the img tags from the downloaded HTML you can apply a simple XSLT with  [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

This is the XSLT (a variation of an example I found at http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity ) `delimg.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0">

  <!-- Remove img tag -->
  <xsl:template match="img" />

  <!-- IdentityTransform -->
  <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then call xmlstarlet with the `--html` option:

```
 curl <url> | xmlstarlet tr --html delimg.xslt > output.html
```